# Prove that $\forall n > 1 \quad2^n - 1 \pmod n \neq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove that $\forall n > 1, \quad2^n - 1 \pmod n \neq 0$

I've thought of the induction but I can't figure out how to prove the step. Fermat's theorem (and its variations) aren't particularly useful as well. Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how to solve this, but perhaps this will be useful: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2005&task=show_msg&msg=1441.0004

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer and more general. If anything is still not clear please feel welcome to ask questions. Note that Bezout's Lemma is not needed, only the fact that if $\,a^n\equiv 1\,$ then the order of $\,a\,$ divides $\,n.\ \ $

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume you have got a $n>1$, so that $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. Take the smallest prime divisor $p$ of $n$.

You have $p\;|\;n\;|\;2^n-1$, hence $2^n\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

But you have also, from [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), that $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Since $p-1$ and $n$ are coprime, you have thus by [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), some $a,b$ such that $a(p-1)+bn=1$, and then

$$1\equiv(2^{p-1})^a\cdot (2^n)^b \equiv 2^{a(p-1)+bn}\equiv 2^1 \pmod{p}$$

Thus $2^1\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, or equivalently $p\;|\;1$, but this is not possible.

Comment: Could you please explain, how does $2^1 \equiv 1 \mod p$ emerge?

Comment: @Arkadiy edited

Answer (score 4):

A counterexample $\,n\,$ i.e.  $\ n\mid 2^n-1\,$ would contradicts the more general theorem below.

**Theorem** $\,\ \ \ m,n>1,\,\ m\mid 2^{\large n}-1\,\Rightarrow\, \ell(m) > \ell(n),\ \ $   $\ell(x) =\,$ least prime factor of $\,x $

**Proof** $\quad\ \, {\rm mod}\,\ p = \ell(m)\!:\,\ 2^{\large n}\equiv 1\equiv\, 2^{\large\color{}{ p-1}}\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\ \ell(m) = p > {\rm ord}\,2\color{#80f}{ \ge \ell(n)}$

**Remark** $\,\ $ The $ $ [key dea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20490/242) $ $ is: $\ \  2^n\equiv 1,\,\ \color{#0a0}{2\not\equiv 1}\,$ implies the order of $\,2\,$ is $\,\color{#80f}{\ge\ {\rm least\  prime}\,\ q\mid n},\ $ because the order  must divide $\,n,\,$ and is $\color{}{\neq \color{#c00}1}$ (else $\,\color{#0a0}{2^{\color{#c00}{\large 1}}\equiv 1})$.