# Find all the primes that satisfy $p \mid 2^p - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I just want somebody to verify that my work is correct.

> Find all prime numbers $p$ such that $p \mid 2^p - 1$.

My claim is that there no such prime that satisfies this.

If $pk = 2^p - 1$, we must have $2^p - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. By using [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we can deduce that $2^p \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$, and so we must also have $2^p - 1 \equiv 2 - 1 \equiv 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. But $p$ is prime, so $p$ can't divide $1$, and consequently there is no no prime $p$ that will satisfy the above.

Comment: Why do you have that 1 is equivalent to $0$ mod p?

Comment: since we have $2^p - 1$ $\equiv$ 0 (mod p) but $2^p$ $\equiv$ 2 so we have $2^p$ - 1 $\equiv$ 1 $\equiv$ 0 (mod p)

Comment: any comment @MichaelBurr?

Comment: It's what I get for posting from my phone.  The proof looks good.

Comment: Looks good to me too. Now write it down properly.

Comment: I would suggest putting the $\equiv 0$ closer to the $2^p-1$ to indicate that it comes from the $p\mid 2^p-1$ and not from the other calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. $\,n\nmid 2^n-1\,$ for $\,n>1\,$ more generally, by the following

**Theorem** $\,\ \ \ m,n>1,\,\ m\mid 2^{\large n}-1\,\Rightarrow\, \ell(m) > \ell(n),\ \ $   $\ell(x) =\,$ least prime factor of $\,x $

**Proof** $\quad\ \, {\rm mod}\,\ p = \ell(m)\!:\,\ 2^{\large n}\equiv 1\equiv\, 2^{\large\color{}{ p-1}}\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\ \ell(m) = p > {\rm ord}\,2\color{#80f}{ \ge \ell(n)}$

**Remark** $\,\ $ The $ $ [key dea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20490/242) $ $ is: $\   2^n\equiv 1,\,\ \color{#0a0}{2\not\equiv 1}\,$ implies the order of $\,2\,$ is $\,\color{#80f}{\ge\ {\rm least\  prime}\,\ q\mid n},\ $ since the order  must divide $\,n,\,$ and is $\color{}{\neq \color{#c00}1}\,$ (else $\,\color{#0a0}{2^{\color{#c00}{\large 1}}\equiv 1}),\,$ i.e. the least nontrivial divisor of $\,n\,$ is its least prime factor (by *uniqueness* of prime factorizations).