# Variant of classic orders problem

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $n \ge 2$ such that $n$ divides $2^n-3$.

This is a variant of the classic problem find all $n$ such that $n$ divides $2^n \pm 1$, which can be done using orders. However I've tried the same methods on this variant without success.

Comment: Yes, for $n^2\pm 1$ there are nice solutions, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397224/show-that-n-does-not-divide-2n-1-where-n-is-an-integer-greater-than-1). It looks like that there is no $n\ge 2$ dividing $2^n-3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think that the method of solving the case $2^n\pm1$ work here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde there are such $n$, but they are all big. See the answer I have posted.

Comment: A later question asked for the smallest such $n$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035344/what-is-the-smallest-integer-n-such-that-2n-equiv-3-mod-n

Comment: @GerryMyerson Very interesting (+1), and this after four years!

Answer (score 1):

This case is harder than the case $2^n\pm1$ and I test this for all $n<7,000,000$ and in all cases $n \nmid 2^n-3$.

When $n$ is a prime number $n\nmid2^n-3$ by Fermat's little theorem. And I find that it's sufficient to check this for all square-free numbers. Because $$p|2^q-3\iff p|2^{q.p^k}-3$$
when $p$ is a prime number. Because  $(2^q)^{p}-3\equiv 2^q-3 \pmod{p}$ .

Answer (score 1):

Integers $n\ge2$ such that $n$ divides $2^n-3$ are tabulated [here](http://oeis.org/A050259). Only five are currently known. The smallest is $4700063497$ so it's no surprise that testing up to $7,000,000$ failed to find any. Finding *all* such $n$, as OP desires, is hopeless. Even deciding whether there are infinitely many is hopeless.