# There is no $(n,k)\ne(1,1)$ such that $n$ divides $2^k-1$ and $k$ divides $2^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $n_1, n_2$ integers. Show that if 
>   $$n_1|2^{n_2}-1 \, \,  n_2|2^{n_1}-1$$
>   then $n_1=n_2=1$.

I want a little hint for this problem. I tried to use the proof of

> There is no $n>1$ such that $n$ divides $2^n-1$

but I got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that both $n_1,n_2$ are odd and $>1$. Let $p_1$ be the smallest prime divisor of $n_1$, $p_2$ the smallest prime divisor of $n_2$. Then $p_1$ divides both $2^{n_2}-1$ and $2^{p_1-1}-1$, hence $p_1$ divides $2^{\gcd(n_2,p_1-1)}-1$. Similarly, $p_2$ divides $2^{\gcd(n_1,p_2-1)}-1$. If $p_2\leq p_1$, $p_2\mid 2^{\gcd(n_1,p_2-1)}-1$ implies $p_2=1$, contradiction. Similarly, if $p_1\leq p_2$, $p_1\mid 2^{\gcd(n_2,p_1-1)}-1$ implies $p_1=1$, contradiction.

This is *exactly* [the proof you probably mentioned](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397231/44121), with a minor twist.

Comment: I get too close. Thanks

Comment: You are missing something, why does $p_1$ divide $gcd(n_2,p_1-1)$?

Comment: @YTS: oh, sorry. I wrote $\gcd(\ldots,\ldots)$ in place of $2^{\gcd(\ldots,\ldots)}-1$. Now fixed.

Comment: Why if $p_2|2^{gcd(n_1,p_2-1)}-1$ and $p_2\leq p_1$ implies $p_2$.

Comment: If $p_2\leq p_1$, $p_2-1\leq p_1-1$ splits as a product of primes $< p_1$. Since the smallest prime divisor of $n_1$ is $p_1$, $\gcd(n_1,p_2-1)=1$.