# $n$ divides $2^n-1$ $\implies n=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $n\mid (2^n-1)$, then $n=1$.

Somehow I am unsure if I got this right, my 'proof' seems to 'easy'. Can you please give me feedback?

So I take a prime divisor $p\mid n$. Then $p\mid (2^n-1)$, hence $2^n\equiv 1\mod p.$

So $2$ has multiplicative order $n$ in $\Bbb F_p^\times$ and therefore, by Lagrange's theorem, $n\mid (p-1)$. But since we also have $p\mid n$, this is only possible for $p=1$.

Comment: No, $x^n=1$ in a group does not imply that the order of $x$ is $n$; it only implies that the order of $x$ _divides_ $n$.

Comment: Right that's more reasonable

Comment: a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20487/for-n-geq-2-show-that-n-nmid-2n-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For $n \geq 2$, show that $n \nmid 2^{n}-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20487/for-n-geq-2-show-that-n-nmid-2n-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $ $  mod $\rm\color{#c00}{least}$ prime $\,p\mid n\!:\ 2^n \equiv  1\Rightarrow\,  2\,$ has order $\,k\mid n\,\color{#c00}{\Rightarrow}\ k \ge$ $\,p\,\Rightarrow\, 2^{p-1}\!\not\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

The  [key Idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20490/242) is: $ $ if $\ a\not\equiv 1,\,\ a^n\equiv 1\,$ then the order of $\,a\,$ is $\,\ge\,$ least prime  $\,p\mid n.$

Comment: Are you a bot? That answer came so damn quick, i couldn't even type it that fast.

Comment: @MyNameIs It's one of my old sci.math answers, where it was a FAQ.

Comment: So from $2^n\equiv 1\mod p$ we can only conclude that $2$ has order a divisor of $n$ in $\Bbb F_p^\times$?

Comment: @MyNameIs That's all we need here.  Every divisor $>1$ of $\,n\,$ is $\ge$ the least prime factor $\,p\,$ of $\,n\,$ (by uniqueness of prime factorizations).

Comment: Thank you. In the last step you said $k\geq p$ implies $2^{p-1}\not\equiv1$. How did you conclude that?

Comment: At least he didn't answer it before it was asked. Actually, he did.

Comment: @MyNameIs By definition, order = smallest power  $\,k\,$ such  $\,2^k\equiv  1,\,$ so all smaller powers are $\not\equiv 1,\,$ so this is true for the smaller power $\,p-1 < k,\ $ i.e. $\,2^{p-1}\not\equiv 1,\,$ contra little Fermat.