# Prove that $\frac{2^n-1}n\notin\Bbb N$ for natural $n>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let
>   $$X(n)=\frac{2^n-1}n;n\in\Bbb N; n>1$$
>   Prove that $X(n)\notin\Bbb N$.

My try: check this for $n=2$. Then
$$X(n+1)=\frac{2^n-1}{n+1}+\frac{2^n}{n+1}$$

So if $n+1$ is odd then $\frac{2^n}{n+1}$ can't be integer, if $n+1$ is even $\frac{2^n-1}{n+1}$ can't be integer.

And then I thought proof is over, however, I realized – this doesn't cover cases where sum of remainders of both fractions is equal to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement to prove is equivalent to$$2^n\not\equiv1\bmod n,n\in\Bbb N,n>1$$
We split the proof into two cases depending on the parity of $n$.

*Case 1:* $n$ is even. Then the proof is obvious, since $2^n\bmod n$ must be even as well.

*Case 2*: $n$ is odd, so $\gcd(2,n)=1$. By Carmichael's theorem $2^{\lambda(n)}\equiv1\bmod n$, where $\lambda$ denotes the Carmichael function. But $2\mid\lambda(n)$ for $n\ge3$, so $\lambda(n)\nmid n$ since $n$ is odd. This implies $2^n\not\equiv1\bmod n$ since $\lambda(n)$ is the least exponent that will yield a residue of 1 and any higher such exponents are multiples of it.

Therefore the statement is true for all $n>1$.

Comment: Nice proof! Is there a proof that doesn't involve Carmichael's theorem?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Thought of using Euler's theorem, but then realised the exponent given by that isn't minimal. Interestingly enough I just finished a number theory module in my high school, and that module taught Euler's theorem but not Carmichael's. It's a pretty easy strengthening though.

Comment: Yeah, Euler's Theorem isn't strong enough. Pretty much all you need is that the minimal exponent is even.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes, Carmichael is a bit overkill here, see e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/20490/242) for a proof avoiding it.